# How to add websocket data to watson speech to text queue

Tags: python, flask, websocket, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I want to have continuous two-way transcription of audio recorded in a browser that is sent through a Python Flask backend to Watson Speech to Text. I can successfully send the audio to the server and send results to the browser.

Additionally, the code gives messages indicating that it successfully connects to the IBM Watson speech to text api. However, I can't seem to add the audio data from within the server to the audio_source queue required by watson python sdk. That is, no transcription is occurring.

I'm basing my approach on the speech to text using microphone example found here: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/blob/master/examples/microphone-speech-to-text.py

I'm using the approach shown here for the Flask websocket connection:
https://github.com/diewland/Flask-SocketIO-Audio

This is just some boilerplate for context:

```
from ibm_watson import SpeechToTextV1
from ibm_watson.websocket import RecognizeCallback, AudioSource
from threading import Thread, Lock
from Queue import Queue, Full

CHUNK = 1024
BUF_MAX_SIZE = CHUNK * 10
# Buffer to store audio
q = Queue(maxsize=int(round(BUF_MAX_SIZE / CHUNK)))
audio_source = AudioSource(q, True, True)

class MyRecognizeCallback(RecognizeCallback):
    def __init__(self):
        RecognizeCallback.__init__(self)

    def on_transcription(self, transcript):
        print('=======================')
        print(transcript)
        print('=======================')

    def on_connected(self):
        print('Connection was successful')

    def on_error(self, error):
        print('Error received: {}'.format(error))

    def on_inactivity_timeout(self, error):
        print('Inactivity timeout: {}'.format(error))

    def on_listening(self):
        print('Service is listening')

    def on_hypothesis(self, hypothesis):
        print(hypothesis)

    def on_data(self, data):
        print('=======================')
        print(data)
        print('=======================')

    def on_close(self):
        print("Connection closed")


def recognize_using_weboscket(*args):
    mycallback = MyRecognizeCallback()
    speech_to_text.recognize_using_websocket(audio=audio_source,
                                             content_type='audio/l16; rate=44100',
                                             recognize_callback=mycallback,
                                             interim_results=True)
```

I think the issue may be where I am starting the recognize_using_websocket thread (below). It does connect and give me messages that it is listening. I've tried a number of different ways to start this recognize_using_websockets thread, but this is the only one that 1) appears to connect to watson, 2) doesn't lock the code up somewhere else, and 3) still outputs a correct audio recording at the end.

```
@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/transcription')
def test_connect():
    global thread
    with thread_lock:
       if thread is None:
            thread = socketio.start_background_task(target=recognize_using_weboscket)

    session['audio'] = []

    emit('my_response', {'data': 'Connected', 'count': 0})
```

However, the queue (q) never changes when I add more data to it using `q.put(data)` below. I think the context of the audio_source / queue might not be available in the way I think it is.

```
@socketio.on('audio', namespace='/transcription')
def handle_my_custom_event(audio):
        values = OrderedDict(sorted(audio.items(), key=lambda t:int(t[0]))).values()
    session['audio'] += values
    q.put(list(values))
    print('queue size:', q.qsize())
    print(list(values)[-1])
```

The watson STT using microphone uses a pyaudio callback to add new data to the queue, which I'm replacing with the websocket callback above to try and mimic this behavior.

```
# define callback for pyaudio to store the recording in queue
def pyaudio_callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    try:
        q.put(in_data)
    except Full:
        pass # discard
    return (None, pyaudio.paContinue)
```

The queue size never changes even though the received audio values change appropriately (the Flask-SocketIO-Audio example above includes a file write out and even with this added code, the output wav file is correct). I don't seem to be properly changing the queue and/or audio-source to send data to watson.

I'm also entirely unsure about the format of the data that the browser is sending. There's some processing done before writing the data to a wave file and the STT microphone example seems to suggest that it's probably audio/l16 but I'm not sure if I need to process the data any further before submitting it to the queue.

Comment: I figured out that I was in fact adding items to the queue. They were just coming out faster than I could print them. My issue was entirely due to incorrect data format, but Watson wasn't throwing an error.